# CSS две тени одному блоку

Tags: css, box-shadow

подскажите как можно задать две тени одному блоку div, погуглив я нахожу только варианты с внутренней тенью: `box-shadow: inset -8px 8px 25px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 6px 4px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);`, но мне нужна внешняя, использовал тот же самый синтаксис ничего не работает(обе тени пропадают), желательно сделать это без других блоков, псевдо элементы последнее дело, кто знает как реализовать? Сейчас у меня такой вид CSS:

```
box-shadow: 9px 9px 16px 0px rgba(163, 177, 198, 0.5,), -9px -9px 16px 0px rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
```

Comment: У вас лишняя запятая перед закрывающей скобкой: `rgba(163, 177, 198, 0.5,)`

Comment: Точно, вы правы, как можно было не заметить(

Answer (score 0):

Погуглил на английском и заметил что передаю большее количество параметров, вот рабочий вариант   `box-shadow: -9px -9px 16px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5),  9px 9px 16px rgba(163, 177, 198, 0.5);`

Answer (score 0):

Еще один из методов, спрятать такой же блок но пустой под первый и добавить там тень.

Comment: Я писал об этом, просто не правильно выразился и назвал их псевдоэлементами:D